# Use Ajax actionlink for entire table row

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, actionlink

At the moment I am using the following code to display information in a partial view below my table -

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(
                item.FirstName,
                "DisplayApplication",
                new { ID = item.ColleagueID },
                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Application" }
            )
        </td>
        <td>
...
        </td>
        <td>
...
        </td>
        <td>
...
        </td>
        <td>
...
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However I want to make the entire table row to be clickable not just the person's first name. I can't seem to find a similar question to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could always do it in a bit of a hacky way...
This javascript is not exactly robust - jQuery might be safer, but it should at least work with any luck!

Basically I've hidden the original link (with the ajax event hooked up on click), and created a dummy copy next to it. Then added an onClick event for the entire row that fires the click event on the original link! The reason why I've hidden the original link is to prevent the click event firing twice when the link is clicked directly.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr onClick="this.children[0].children[0].click();">
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(
                item.FirstName,
                "DisplayApplication",
                new { ID = item.ColleagueID },
                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Application" },
                new { style="display:none;" }
            )
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">@item.FirstName</a>
        </td>
        <td>
...
        </td>
        <td>
...
        </td>
        <td>
...
        </td>
        <td>
...
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works great, thanks, Although I thought there would be a more 'standard' way of achieving this. It also works fine with just removing the <a> tag and getting rid of the style line you added, was there a reason for that?

Comment: Glad its working for you, and yes I feel there should be a better/more standard solution too, just can't think of one! As stated the reason for the hidden style and dummy `<a> `tag was simply to prevent the ajax callback from firing twice if the link is clicked directly (because it is within the `<tr>`). Although without testing I'm not 100% certain if that would happen or not. Probably depends if the update target contains the table or not.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer, thank you, and it lead me to this alternative version...

```
<tr onclick="DoAjaxCall(@row.Key)">
```

And this is the Javascript function, where "preview" is my action...

```
function DoAjaxCall(row) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Preview", "myController")' + '?rowKey=' + row;
        $.get(url, null, function (data) { $("#previewPane").html(data); });
    }
```

And my page contains a simple div element...

```
<div id="previewPane"></div>
```

And in my controller, I have used nullable parameters...

```
    public PartialViewResult Preview(int? rowKey = null)
    {
        if(rowKey != null)
        { 
            /* do stuff */
        }
        return PartialView("_Preview");
    }
```